Research associate salary
I am a professor working with an undergraduate in computer science in the US who is interested in working in my lab for one or two years post-graduation to gain research experience before applying to PhD programs.
Commonly, undergraduate research jobs during the school year or summer are unpaid. However, this is a bit different since research would be their primary job responsibility.
I am wondering what is the salary norms for these post-bac / undergraduate research associate positions? Are they normally unpaid, or are they paid essentially minimum wage?

What does your department or HR say? Why do you want to take advantage of someone like that?

You can't ethically employ someone for a year or two without paying them an adequate salary!

@WolfgangBangerth, I can't speak for this person, but at my institution, the students either get academic credit or pay, but cannot get both.  Nearly always they prefer academic credit and are thus unpaid.  This is not an option during the summer, because the registrar doesn't offer summer classes, so we always pay undergrads during the summer (and as a side note, their FICA status changes as well because they are not enrolled in classes at that time).

"salary norms for these post-bac / undergraduate research associate" Are you asking about post-bacs or undergrad RAs?

I'm not sure whether this is something that varies enormously with in the US, so I'm not voting to close. But I'm also conscious that answers saying "$n-$m" will become outdated quite fast, so I suggest focusing not on specific figures but on how to find them out.

@yourfriendlyresearchadmin I read the question as saying that the person wants to work full time after graduation, not as an undergraduate student assistant for credit. They wouldn't even be students any more at that time. I do not think it ethical to let someone work for free full time for 1-2 years.

@WolfgangBangerth, I read it the same way.  In my experience helping faculty get folks on payroll, they usually don't have experience with the hundreds of possible positions and rely on their current experience (e.g., no pay for undergrads who get academic credit) and don't realize what rules are out there for slightly different positions -- e.g., FLSA could kick in and after graduating from undergrad but not being enrolled in an academic program, which ironically means they could make more than being a graduate student.  The laws are really complicated.

There's usually a particular job title for this sort of post-bac student; I've encountered "Research Intern" and "Junior Scientist", there may be a different title that is normal at your institution. To me, in the US, "research associate" is usually a title for a postdoctoral researcher.
These jobs are not well-paid, but the compensation is much better than minimum wage. I would guess an equivalent of $18-25/hour minimum (if the low end of that is near the minimum wage where you are, then you're in a high cost area and should be paying on the higher end if not above). Comparable to a grad student stipend, at least (though without any tuition to remit). They likely qualify for standard benefits, as well, and in the US it's legally required to provide health insurance for someone working full time so that's definitely included.

Just to show how varied titles are, "associate" doesn't have that connotation for me, but I believe it. I have also seen "technologist" and "research professional."

Research administrator from the US here.  I do appointments and payroll, so I have some background for you to explore at your institution.  All of the rules will vary based on your institution and even your state.
One question is which office will offer the job.  If the person is classed in an academic position, different rules apply than if they are classed as staff under an HR office.  The reason is that there are different federal laws that apply to academic vs. staff positions.  One specific example is how the US Department of Labor defines "trainee".  Each institution has to define "trainee" given these guidelines and be consistent.  This is why some institutions class students as employees and others do not.  So in this way, I advise you to look into how your institution is defining these jobs.
With that being said, one of the pitfalls of a potential hire not being enrolled in an academic program and also not having a PhD is that some places will argue that these individuals fall under FLSA.  You will see that the FLSA pay standards are quite high, and in fact could be substantially more than those in a PhD program -- it's a real dilemma.  Note the substantial increase that will be effective 1 Jan 2025.
At my institution, it's easiest if we can hire someone as a temp, but that is not always the need of the PI, who may want a year-long commitment, and our temp jobs do not offer this option.  Our staff positions come with substantial fringe, severance, and other costs.  You will need to be thoughtful and ask a lot of questions of your research administrator and payroll offices in order to get the correct appointment type.  I agree with the prior answer that "Research Associate" is usually more senior than postdoc.  "Research Assistant" is usually the more lowly position.  It is best to communicate the attributes that you are looking for and not a specific title.  At my institution, we have hundreds of flavors of positions, and knowing the attributes means we will find the title for the PI that matches the attributes.
